# Invalidation schema due to wrong audit name column with springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, audit

I'm currently working on a rest api for a old java application using springboot.

When I scan my entities, I have :

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [rev] in table [schema.object_aud].
```

Indeed, my rev column is named "revision_id".

I don't want to change this name because it's used in many applications and I don't want side effects...

How can I configure bootstrap to check that name instead of "rev".

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution if someone read this post :
In application.yml/application.properties, I add these lines

```
spring.jpa.properties:
      org.hibernate.envers.revision_field_name: revision_id
      org.hibernate.envers.revision_type_field_name: revision_type
```

And it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, You have a different name of column in entity class.
You can define your rev attriute with this annotation :

@Column(name = "revision_id")

Now the validation will look for column "revision_id" in the schema.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's not exactly my case... I use the library of my first application and I use these entity. The Audit entity is not managed by myself but with @ Audited annotation. Springboot can check it and deduce that an audit table exists. Then Springboot checks if the column exists but it dosn't have the same configuration as me. Your solution should works for @ Entity classes :)